# how to do nested $$eval in puppetter javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

so how to do $$eval inside $$eval?
I've tried several ways but it doesn't work

```
const dataDettail = await detailPage.$$eval(
    "div.site-content",
        function (details) {
          //I want to do $$eval again in here
    }
);
```

Comment: Nested `$$eval` isn't possible because `$$eval` only exists on the Puppeteer `page` object running in NodeJS. The callback to the first `$$eval` runs in the browser, so you have access to browser functions like `document.querySelectorAll`. It's better to explain what you're really trying to achieve by doing nested evals to avoid the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Answer (score 1):

Once you're there, you're already in the browser context.

Maybe you want something like:

```
page.$$eval('div.site-content', divs => divs.map(div => div.innerText))
```

Answer (score 0):

if `const dataDettail`  is a promise then you should run your second `.$$eval` in the `.then()`